# Text shorcuts with @ symbols are not working in OS X

Tags: macos, ios, keyboard, shortcut

On my iPhone, I've setup text shortcuts that allow me to quickly enter email addresses. For example, typing `x@g` for example might resolve to `xyz@gmail.com`.

These shortcuts have been synced to my Mac, along with all my other devices, but it seems that having an `@` symbol as part of the shortcut, means they don't work in OS X (running Yosemite right now).

I have done the same for domains, so `google` might resolve to `http://www.google.com`, and that works.

I could always create an OS X friendly shortcut, but what I'd really like to know is if it's possible to get the `@` symbol to work in OS X as a shortcut?

Comment: Interesting. I have 2 that work on Yosemite. Do you have instances where they don't work?

Comment: I've tried in the Notes app, the Twitter widget in notification centre and in Chrome. Shortcuts without the @ symbol work in all those places.

Comment: Try recreating them on your Mac instead of the phone. See if that works.

Comment: I tried that before posting up, just didn't work. At first I thought they hadn't even synced but they had and I can configure them on both my iOS and OS X devices.

Comment: I can't duplicate.  I made a shortcut on my iPhone (z@e) which expands to: xyz@example.com every time on my Mac running Yosemite.  Hope you find a solution. Cheers

Comment: Expands in OS X?

Comment: Yup.  In Notes and even here: xyz@example.com (works after hitting space bar)

Comment: I didn't think Chrome supported expansion. Try Safari